# Creating a calendar in PHP

Tags: php, html, calendar

Recently, someone very kindly gave me some code for creating a table that simulated a schedule in HTML - below is the code

```
    function make_row( $slot , array $list )
   {
      $output = '';
      $output .= '<tr><td>' . $slot . '</td>';
      for ( $i = 1; $i <= 7 ; $i++ )
      {
         $details = '&nbsp;';
         if ( isset($list[ $i ]) )
         {  
            $details = $list[ $i ];
         }
         $output .= '<td>' . $details . '</td>';
      }
      $output .= '</tr>';
      return $output;
   }

   $timeslot = '';
   $item = array();
   while ($eventrow = mysql_fetch_array($sqlevents)) 
   {
      $timeslot = $eventrow['PreferredStart'];
      $day = (int)$eventrow['idDay'];

      if ( !is_array( $item[ $timeslot ] ) )
      {
         $item[ $timeslot ] = array();
      }

      $item[ $timeslot ][ $day ] = $eventrow['EventDetails'];
   }

   foreach( $item as $slot => $list )
   {
      echo make_row( $slot, $list );
   }
```

However, my DB table setup has changed.  I now have half hour slots instead of full hour ones.  The table renders correctly, but I am trying to ensure that if someone enters an appointment, then the whole block is marked in the calendar, not just the start time.  Can someone help me to add the end time, as well as the timeslots in between?

Many thanks,
Brett

Comment: where is your html code?? better to paste whole code in http://www.ideone.com or http://www.codepad.org or http://www.pastebin.com and refer a link here

Comment: Hi diEcho, outside of this code block, i only have <table> and then the <th> fields and a </table> at the end.  The SQL i am using to populate it is below under eykanal's answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty tough to answer without knowing the database structure or the sql query that produced `$sqlevents`, but it looks like the timeslot is simply taken straight from the database:

```
$timeslot = $eventrow['PreferredStart'];
```

You could change this by finding the end time (I assume named `PreferredEnd` in the database, but you'll obviously have to check that for yourself, as I don't know your database schema) and adding the two together:

```
$timeslot_start = $eventrow['PreferredStart'];
$timeslot_end   = $eventrow['PreferredEnd'];   // I'm gonna assume this is right

$timeslot = $timeslot_start.'-'.$timeslot_end; // Make a new field combining both
```

Now your `$timeslot` var should have both start and end time in it.

Comment: Hi eykanal, thanks for the advice, but I don't think this is quite right.  PreferredEnd is indeed my endtime, but I need the timeslots being called to generate the time fields on the y-axis of the table.  My SQL is below

Comment: $sqlevents = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Timeslots LEFT JOIN Event ON Timeslots.idTimeslot = Event.PreferredStart AND idTeacher = '$idTeacher' WHERE Timeslots.idTimeslot <> 0");

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying, but I can't really visualize it without seeing the page in action, or at least a screenshot. From the code you posted it's not evident how this is supposed to be displayed; I figured it was just outputting, e.g., "10:00-11:00, stuff".

Comment: I now need the table to get filled with BOTH start time and end time and the timeslots in between.  So, in my timeslots table, 07:00 = 1, 07:30 = 2, etc all the way up to 22:30 = 32.

Comment: That is correct eykanal, the table is Days across the top, Timeslots (07:00, 07:30...)down the left side.  Currently, I can get one 'field' filled, so say Monday at 7am will say Stuff, but i cannot get the end time to work. if I want column Monday, from 7am-9am to all say stuff, i cannot do this at present.

Comment: I'm afraid there's too much unknown here for us to help you. The query depends on the schema of the database, and you haven't posted that. It sounds like you're pretty unfamiliar with php/mysql programming... I would suggest getting someone more familiar with this sort of stuff to help you out.

Comment: Which fields do you need to know eykanal?  I think the only relevant ones would be 'PreferredStart' and 'PreferredEnd'